# passing data between controller.swift file

Tags: ios, parameters

I get 
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Error.

on ViewController.swift.

I initiate serviceController.swift to get json data.

appDelegate.swift

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
 var mainView=ViewController()
...
..
```

serviceController.swift

```
self.appDelegate.mainView.gettingData(result:results)
```

ViewController.swift

```
public func gettingData(result:Array<String>){

        print("gettingData")
         print(self.currentTime) //it is nill
        print(self.userId)
        print(self.name)

       self.name.text="ss" . //here error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

maybe It's because initiating on AppDelegate.swift? 
then, How can I pass data from servicecontroller to viewController.swift?

Comment: You are just creating an instance of `viewController` out of nowhere; so none of it's `@IBOutlet`s will be set.  You need to get the reference to your actual view controller.  Using the app delegate in this way is not the right approach.  You should pass a completion handler to your service controller function so that it can pass the data back to the view controller